# MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard refuses to reverse engineer table and gives no reason why

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm trying to migrate a database from my development machine to the staging environment using the Migration Wizard in MySQL Workbench on my development machine. The Migration Wizard is refusing to reverse engineer one critical table.

I am not a database admin by trade; I am a developer with one objective, to copy my database from my machine to another. My search on the term `mysql workbench migration Table not reverse engineered` turned up some SO posts from people migrating between DB platforms and some information about reverse engineering in MySQL but nothing that helped me determine the problem. For griggles, I ran the Reverse Engineering command in Workbench hoping it would fail and give me some useful information. But  the Reverse Engineering command ran without a hitch and produced a correct relationship graph.

So I have a migration that's refusing to export a critical table, and no details about what's wrong or how I can fix it. I'm not happy.

What can I do to determine why the Migration Wizard isn't reverse-engineering my table? And exactly how can Migration Wizard fail to reverse-engineer it when the Reverse Engineering command handles it without fail?

This is the log from the Reverse Engineer Source step, snipped for relevance:

```
Starting...
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting...
Connecting to Mysql@localhost:3306...
Connected to Mysql@localhost:3306, 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
Connect to source DBMS done
Reverse engineer selected schemas....
Reverse engineering my_database from def
- Preparing...
- Preparing...
Reverse engineering tables from my_database
<snip>
- Retrieving table my_database.licenses...
- Reverse engineering my_database.licenses...
<snip>
Reverse engineering triggers from my_database
Reverse engineering stored procedures from my_database
Reverse engineering functions from my_database
- Reverse engineered 25 objects
WARNING: Table licenses was referenced from another table, but was not reverse engineered
Reverse engineer selected schemas finished
Post-processing of reverse engineered schemas...
Post-processing of reverse engineered schemas done
Tasks finished with warnings and/or errors; view the logs for details
Finished performing tasks.
```